# How to populate array from a sheet column in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array like this :

```
myColumns = Array("Serial","Practice","Manager", "QTD")
```

But I want to fetch its values from a sheet to make it more dynamic. (The values & their number may vary)

[image]

So I tried this to affect the range from A2 to last value of the column to my array:

```
myColumns = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
```

It results in :

```
UBound(myColumns) -> 4 -> OK
```

BUT when I do this :

```
s = myColumns(3) -> Subscribe out of range !
```

How is that possible?

How can I populate it correctly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Transpose` is a good friend of yours, if you are **parsing a single column:**

```
Sub TestMe1()
    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A10"))

    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        Debug.Print myArr(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

[image]

---

If you are **parsing a single row**, you should transpose twice:

```
Sub TestMe2()
    Dim myArr As Variant
    With Application
        myArr = .Transpose(.Transpose(Range("A1:AI1")))
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

If you are simply **parsing multiple range or without .Transpose()**, you have to refer to both columns and rows:

[image]

---

- [An article I wrote about it some time ago.](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-excel-how-to-convert-range-to-array-easily/)

Comment: @Takichiii - just keep in mind that this **magic** works so smoothly for singles rows/columns. By multiples, the game is changed a bit.

Comment: I appreciate your updated full answer, thank you so much!!