# Subscript is out of Range Error when Parsing Range to Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I have a code in a userform in vba excel:

```
Dim TimeArray() As Variant
TimeArray = Worksheets("Data").Range("E1:E30").Value
MsgBox TimeArray(0)
```

The error is

> "Subscript is out of range"

while my range (E1:E3) have data.

Comment: The way you assigned values to the array means that the LBound value of the array is = 1 not 0.

Answer (score 2):

Converting range to array is a standard procedure in VBA. In general, when you do it explicitly like this `TimeArray = Worksheets("Data").Range("E1:E30").Value`, VBA translates it to a 2D-array. Thus, to get the first value you have to ask `TimeArray(1, 1)`, because the cells in Excel start with column 1 and row 1:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim TimeArray() As Variant
    TimeArray = Worksheets(1).Range("E1:E30")
    MsgBox TimeArray(1, 1)

End Sub
```

---

With `Application.Transpose()`, you can force a 1-dimensional array from one column:

```
Sub TestMeAndTransposeMe()

    Dim TimeArray() As Variant
    TimeArray = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("E1:E30"))

    MsgBox TimeArray(1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(TimeArray) To UBound(TimeArray)
        Debug.Print i; TimeArray(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can see additional examples of the useage of `Application.Transpose()` here:

- [How to populate array from a sheet column in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570154/how-to-populate-array-from-a-sheet-column-in-excel/50570250#50570250)